# Controlling 24-bit parallel RGB LCD with 16 bits

Tags: microcontroller, lcd

I'd like to run a 24-bit parallel RGB LCD with 16 bits using the LTDC controller of a [STM32F469ZGT6](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/2f/48/57/b4/79/f7/4f/65/DM00219980.pdf/files/DM00219980.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00219980.pdf).  The screen won't be displaying video or anything too intense, but there will be some anti-aliased fonts and images.  I thought of a few possibilities in how to configure the hardware:

1. Connect the LCD's LSbs (R0-R2, G0-G1, B0-B2) to GND
2. Connect the LSbs to the MSb of each color (R7 --> R0-R2, etc.)
3. Connect the LSbs to the MSbs (R7 --> R2, R6 --> R1, R5 --> R0, etc.)

Option 1 is out because full white could not be achieved.  Option 2 induces a higher overall error than option 3, the latter of which was recommended by a TI rep [in their e2e forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/processors/f/791/t/371040?How-to-connect-of-C6748-s-16-bit-display-data-pins-to-24-bit-RGB-of-TFT-LCD-Display).  However, when asked about performance comparisons, they replied:

> Sorry, we do not have any performance comparison between the two methods.

Is there any evidence -- empirical or otherwise -- that option 3 is superior?  Or is there another, prefereable scheme?

Comment: You could simulate all three in a spreadsheet or directly on your PC's screen, if not the traditional back of an envelope.  Especially try feeding color gradient bars into it and seeing what you get as a result, for example do a graph of the input vs. the output for a single color.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "performance" in this case? Obviously, the third option gives you both full white and full black, with appropriate offsets for all of the in-between values, and it will be a lot more linear than option 2. What more do you want?

Comment: @ChrisStratton good call -- I can try that.

Comment: @DaveTweed what follows your 'obviously' is not totally obvious to me.  I have no experience with displays, and haven't found much wisdom on the interwebs regarding this topic.  Is option 3 the best way then?

Comment: Are you sure the LCD doesn't have the option to change the number of bits used? This is extremely common on most TFT controllers. They normally have an I2C interface that is used to set power control, refresh rate and gamma curves, and this typically has a command to change the interface mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wanted to convert a 5 bit (0-31) to a 8 bit (0-255) number mathematically, what would you do to appropriately scale the range of value?

You would just use the rule of three: *out = in × 255 / 31 = in × 8.22580645...*.

Now, look what your third solution does: it shifts the input by three bits left (because you insert three new bits at the right end): this means multiplying by 8. And, because the new bits you added are actually a copy of MSBs, it is equivalent to then adding the input, shifted to the right, by 2 bits: this means dividing by 4 (if we ignore rounding). See this for a better explanation:

```
           |R4|R3|R2|R1|R0|    input
------------------------------------------------------------
  |R4|R3|R2|R1|R0| 0| 0| 0|    input shifted left by 3 (x8)
+                |R4|R3|R2|    input shifted right by 2 (/4)
= |R4|R3|R2|R1|R0|R4|R3|R2|    output
```

So the equivalent expression is: *out = in × 8 + in / 4*. Wich is *out = in × 8.25*

See? This is almost the same thing, mathematically.

Basically, this method will allow you to take full advantage of your LCD contrast: full black and full whites are maintained (0 translates to 0, 31 translates to 255), and it tries to evenly distribute the steps because the scaling factor is constant (the 8.25 ratio). Of course because of rounding (R1|R0 have been left out during the shift right operation), some steps are a bit bigger than others, but you can't avoid that.

Method 1, in comparison, will not allow you to get full white, but all steps will be equal. In my opinion, rounding errors will be less noticeable than a greyish white.

I'm not sure I understand you method 2, but if I do, the steps will have more errors and be much more irregular than method 3, because it does not translate to a mathematical expression that is just a simple linear scaling of the input by a constant factor (and rounding). There is no advantage to that method whatsoever.

In fact, anything other than method 1 and method 3 will have no advantage.

Comment: Excellent answer -- thank you.  Option 2 was just an easy way to modify an existing PCB (kludging one MSb to three pins is easier than trying to kludge option 3) and seemed like a small upgrade to full brightness from option 1.  It can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you value the most, it has nothing to do with technical performance. Grounding LSBs means you have even steps between values, but miss the full brightness. Driving LSBs from MSBs is same as multiplying so wiring is a bit more complex and you get full white, but steps are uneven. On the other hand, display may follow a gamma curve so output is not linear brightness anyway based on linear input. And having 6 bits of green while there are 5 bits of blue/red shows, so it is worth testing if it is better with 5 bits of each.